Citrix No Longer Works When Using VPN After Upgrading from 22.04 to 23.10 (and 24.04)
Citrix (current version and prior versions) will not start a service (i.e., a .ica file) after the upgrade to 23.10 (also tried 24.04) -- when I use a VPN to access the internet.  It gives the following semi-generic error:
“Cannot connect to the Citrix server: The Citrix SSL relay name could not be resolved (SSL error 40).”
This Citrix guide says the following about the error:
This means that the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the Secure Gateway server is not recognized by the client. Create a DNS record that resolves the FQDN of the Secure Gateway server or create an entry in the host file on the client devices.
I have no idea what that means.  But I can't control the host, and I know that it works with Ubuntu 22.04's settings and the same Citrix install.
On 22.04, I can connect to the exact same Citrix service while connected to the internet via a VPN.
Because I have full system (partition image) backups of my 22.04 instance, I was able to A/B test this.  I copied all of the Citrix files (i.e., /opt/Citrix/ and ~/.ICAClient) from 22.04 to the to the upgraded systems.  But while Citrix will connect to the service with the VPN off, it will not with the VPN on.
I reverted to 22.04 to check if maybe it was the Citrix service -- but it works on 22.04 after reverting.
This all leads me to believe that there is some system networking settings not in the usual Citrix areas that changed between 22.04 and 23.10.
Any suggestions/ideas/solutions?
